# Match Regex unless leading character is a space

Tags: regex

I have three strings, which only two of them must match:

```
c = kj.a(yj.class, ki.f);  //Should match entirely
k = kj.h(yj.class, ki.b);  //Should match entirely
Object a0 = this.l.a(yj.class, this.bo().b(0.5, 0.0, 0.5)).iterator(); // Should NOT match at all
```

In order to differentiate the first two strings from other strings that could be present, I wrote this expression:

```
(\w* = [^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);)
```

But right now, what happens is that the first two strings get matched correctly, but the last gets matched partially, because it has somewhat the same pattern as the first two (the last it should not get matched at all); the last is matched as such: `a0 = this.l.a(yj.class, this.bo().b(0.5, 0.0, 0.5)).iterator();`

How can I prevent the last string from being matched entirely? I am thinking I should check if the fist character is not a space () (or contains one...)

Comment: Take a look at [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: `^\w* = [^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);)` . ^ -> should start with this. But \w* means zero or more occurrences. are you sure?

Comment: one more thing use `\w+` instead of `\w*`

Comment: @SilentMonk When I use that, the first string gets matched, but the second string is not matched anymore? Probably something to do with \n...?

Comment: @Momo, can you please post the code snippet where you are doing regex match?

Comment: @SilentMonk I am using regexr: http://regexr.com/3dh1u

Comment: `(^[^ ]+ = [^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);)` [Look](https://regex101.com/r/bU7wT2/1)

Comment: will work fine..don't worry..check **[here](https://regex101.com/r/wR8oR7/1)**

Comment: @Momo, I have consolidated it as an answer. As you suggested it needed multiline matching.

Answer (score 0):

`/^\w+ = [^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);/mg`

> m - multiline match.
>
> g - global

Answer (score 0):

```
/(^[^ ]+ = [^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bU7wT2/1)

Comment: Could you please add some context to this regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

this regex will only take the lines that do not contain a number before the "="

```
[a-z]\s=[^;]*\.\w\(yj\.class, [^;]*\);
```